# what type of array of CFBundleIconFiles

Tags: iphone, ios

CFBundleIconFiles is type of an array. My question is what type of array is. Should it be NSArray or NSMutableArray. 
Assumed we already have

```
NSDictionary    *plistDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
```

My question is which declaration below is a right one

```
NSMutableArray  *array           =  [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleIconFiles"];
NSArray         *array           =  [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleIconFiles"];
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be NSArray.  There are a few exceptions, but the standard is that when you read collections from files they are immutable by default.  Both of these will compile and work because objectForKey returns `id`, however you will get a runtime error if you try to modify it.